# Is it possible to add a method/interface to a referenced DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

Coding in C# with Visual Studio,

Is it possible to add a method or an interface to a referenced DLL that
I added to my project?

Or the only way is to return to the source of the DLL, add the data &
create a new DLL?

Comment: Depending on source availability, you may consider an adapter to existing functionality, which will add methods you need.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you can extend a class in a referenced DLL. You could use a decompiler if you wanted the classes in a dll, the names of variables and methods may change but you can still see most of the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- **No** you can't add anything to a referenced dll.

2- **Yes**, you need to update the source for that dll and generate a new copy.

if the `dll` is a `class library` in the same solution, you just need to add the method/interface and `Rebuild`.

## Extension Methods:

You can always add an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) to a class that you have no control over, whether it was a core .NET class or a referenced `dll`. Below is an example adding a method to the `String` class:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type.